# Multiple OS vs SIngle OS phone and server development

Tags: iphone, android, linux, windows-phone-7, windows-7

Me and few friends run a little app creation business in our spare time, our current development environment is a 3 macbooks laptops running just snow leopard, 4 asus laptops with dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu and a rubbish test server box that is similar to our vps.

Our setup currently work okayish at the moment, with a few minor issues, like not knowing what version of software we are working on, caused by continually switching operating systems and lost of productivity from being to lazy to switch the laptop we are working, having to unplug it and plug in the new one, including the second monitor, keyboard and mouse.

Our system is far from professional and we are looking to upgrade. This is because we wish to increase our staff and we have some cash saved up, so why not. The phone we are targetting are iOS, android and Win7. Our servers are written in php and json. So my question is basically, how do you guys manage with all these multiple operating systems.

iOS requires mac os x
android can use all
json require linux/mac os x
windows phone 7 requires windows

do you guys use some form of virutalization?
or try those libraries that compile to each phone binary such as unity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many many different ways to solve this and you may have to find what works best for you.  Here are some suggestions though.

- Using the macbooks, set up bootcamp so you can dual boot to OSX or Windows.  This will mean you can use the Macbook for all development without having to bother swapping monitors, etc.  Doing this will leave your other Windows laptops spare which you can use for the next suggestion....
- Set up a central repository for your sourcecode.  Use one of the servers you have, or re-purpose one of the other machines and install a decent source code repository system.  CVS, Git, etc.  There's plenty of resources about these.  This will allow you to keep your code in one place so it won't matter which machine you are working on - you can always get the most recent code.  Plus it will help you track your code changes.  Oh, and don't forget having it all in one place will be much easier for backups (you do do backups, don't you....?)
- Don't fall into the trap of upgrading hardware just because you have some money floating around.  You may just need to use the hardware you have more wisely.  You mention what you have is "far from professional".  You don't need the latest, greatest hardware and software to do development.  I've done iOS development on 4 year old Macbook Pro, used an 8 year old PC as a server for web and database and still use Windows XP every day.
- Depending on how many of you there are, you may not have enough Macbooks.  If this is the case, then perhaps you have some who are specialists in the server-side stuff (ie they don't do iOS development and so don't need the Macs).
- Virtualisation - using VMWare or similar tools are an excellent way of getting more from what you have.  For example, you could have a couple of test servers that aren't very heavily utilised.  Using virtualisation, you could put both of these servers onto one machine.  This will then free up the other box for something else.  It also makes it very easy to backup (you are doing backups, aren't you...?) an entire server and recover it back to the exact state in the case of a hardware failure.  You can also very easily create a server tailored for each client/project and switch between them quickly without having to maintain lots of other stuff (think if you had a web server configured for one project and you then work on another project that needs a different configuration and you change it, then you need to change it back, etc).

EDIT: Update in response to comments.
If using Bootcamp isn't an option, then consider running a Windows and/or Linux virtual machine inside OSX.  Depending on the spec of your macbooks and as long as you don't need very low-level hardware access on Windows, then this would probably work as well and not need to switch in and out using BootCamp.  Same goes for the Linux virtual machine.  I'm a big fan of using Virtual Machines on development environments as it allows you to copy around and switch in and out servers without having to rely on physical hardware connections.  And you can very easily return to a known state with the server configuration and data.

With regards the source control "in the cloud".  I'm not a fan of this approach.  It's my source code and I want to control it.  I don't want to be reliant on some other company and I don't want to hope I've read some Terms and Conditions correctly and I'm not handing over my code to some other company to do what they want with it.  Aside from that, what happens if your internet access goes down and you absolutely must get some coding done for a customer?  If you are relying on another service, then you are risking problems.  Yes, it has advantages for multi-site, they do the backups for you, etc.  But it really isn't a problem unless you have lots of developers spread all across the world.  And even then it isn't necessarily a problem.  You could always do a backup of your code to some package file, encrypt it and then throw that up in the cloud for a backup storage (as well as burning it to disc, writing to another external hard drive and storing them off-site).  But I certainly wouldn't want to rely on an external source control unless I was doing open source stuff.

There's sooooo much more to these subjects and there are many other subjects you will probably encounter along the way of building up your business.

One of the most important things about software development is to keep it organised and to get that organisation part done at the start.  If you are just each keeping a copy of the code on local drives, then changing code and hoping that you haven't changed the same file as someone else, then this will just lead to pain.  The source control aspect is key from the start.

Oh, and did I mention backups?

Comment: wow.. thats really great advice, thanks alot. We tried bootcamp before, and to go mac only approach, but to be honest bootcamp is terrible. We use laptops for mobility, so we can work at dorm rooms and also move and work at the library, mac's window and linux trackpad drivers make it almost impossible to use without a mouse. The small mac hdd also make it a pain to triple boot.

Comment: For our source control we use web based, like kilnhg and bitbucket. We have no backups, our logic is that with multiple web-based source control and automated builds, so if we have a failure all we have to do is hg clone, cd project, sudo python setup.py, we should be covered if code/server/database dies. Is this logic faulty? Should we have a dedicated backup?

Comment: Have you tried bootcamp recently? It has improved very much from the earlier versions. You could also run a VM with a Windows in it if you don't need low-level hardware access. See my updated answer for more comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider the IDE you're using as part of the equation. For instance a good cross platform IDE (Like QT4+) and a centralised code repository on a server will go a long way towards mitigating your working problems. Eclipse, Netbeans and QT4+ are cross platform and will work with all 3 systems. Virtualisation as you mentioned is an option, but first I would decide on the IDE platforms to use before worrying about your dev infrastructure setup.

Comment: We only know the three main phone IDE's, xcode, eclipse and visual studio. For server's we use vim. It just was just harder fighting against the grain, trying to use a non official IDE

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I'm not a pro, but you have two options:

1. Either multiboot your system by installing multiple OSes...(Obviously, you need a separate MACbook)
2. Or use Virtual Machines like VMWare etc.

Personally, I haven't heard much about libraries like Unity etc.

Go for dedicated systems & not just libraries.